# WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls TreeView - Remove Mouseover highlight

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview, windows-10-universal, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm using WinRTXamlToolkit and I'm currently trying to use the TreeView control. It works fine, but whenever I hold my mouse over it or select it, the item is highlighted. It covers the whole text and I would like to change the foreground/background colors it or, ideally, remove the selection color background altogether. Any idea how I can start?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can edit the `Template` of `TreeViewItem` to achieve this. And we can find the [style and template of TreeViewItem](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeViewItem.xaml) at GitHub.

The mouseover effect of the item in TreeView is set by the `Rectangle` named "Hover":

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Hover"
           Fill="#FFBADDE9"
           IsHitTestVisible="False"
           Opacity="0"
           RadiusX="2"
           RadiusY="2"
           Stroke="#FF6DBDD1"
           StrokeThickness="1" />
```

And the "Pressed" `VisualState` in `Button`'s `VisualStateGroup`:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="Hover"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To=".5" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

We can change its color by setting `Fill` property and the opacity by setting `DoubleAnimation.To` property.

The selection effect is like the mouseover effect and is set by the `Rectangle` named "Selection":

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Selection"
           Grid.Column="1"
           IsHitTestVisible="False"
           Opacity="0"
           RadiusX="2"
           RadiusY="2"
           StrokeThickness="1">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="SelectionFill" Color="#FFBADDE9" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
    <Rectangle.Stroke>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="SelectionStroke" Color="#FF6DBDD1" />
    </Rectangle.Stroke>
</Rectangle>
```

And the "Selected" `VisualState` in `TreeViewItem`'s "SelectionStates" `VisualStateGroup`:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="Selection"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To=".75" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

We can remove the selection effect by deleting the animation in this `VisualState` like:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <!--<Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="Selection"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To=".75" />
    </Storyboard>-->
</VisualState>
```

So you can edit `TreeViewItem`'s style and template according to your requirement and give the new `Style` a `x:Key` like

```
<Style x:Key="MyTreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="controls:TreeViewItem">
```

Then use the new style in your `TreeView` by setting `ItemContainerStyle` like following:

```
<controls:TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}">
    <controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
            </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:TreeView>
```